# Windows 7 Task Scheduler BASH Script Fails

Tags: windows, bash, scheduler

In order to use rsync I created a BASH script.  It runs fine from the Cygwin shell in WIN 7 but fails when run from the WIN 7 Task Scheduler.  My Task Scheduler Script is a simple:

c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "~user/rsync_Windows_Backup 2>&1 >> ~user/Documents_cron.log"

The initial directory is set to C:\Cygwin\bin.

My BASH script is a typical rsync command with [options] SRC DEST and some related housekeeping.

The rsync command within the "rsync_Windows_Backup" BASH script is:

```
/bin/time -f "\nElapse (hh:mm:ss.ss) %E" \ 
rsync.exe -v -rltz --chmod=a=rw,Da+x -u "$SRC" "$DEST" >> "$LOG" \ 
2 >> "$LOG"

$ ./rsync_Windows_Backup - succeeds.
```

But the Task Scheduler Job fails carping that it cannot find the DEST Folder that the BASH script references.  When I do a "cd DEST" from the BASH command line the Folder is avialable and can be written to.

I should add some more details that the sender is a WIN 7 desktop that is mapped to a Vista desktop receiver with a drive mapping J:. The BASH script does start but fails with:

```
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/J/DocumentsBackup" failed: No such file or directory (2) rsync error:  error in file IO (code 11)
```

I have tried several ideas to influence how WIN 7 handles mappings and permissions assuming this is the root of the problem.  So far nothing seems to help.

Another characteristic is that the exact same BASH script and Task Scheduler Job does succeed it WIN Vista Business Edition.  So I am assuming there is something in WIN 7 that I am missing.

I am stumped and could use some guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `~user/rsync_Windows_Backup` not `~/rsync_Windows_Backup` ?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I see your point, I can try that syntax also.  It does work as written in Vista though.

Comment: Using ./ does not help.  Still stumped.

Comment: No it should be `~/`.

Comment: I posted an answer. I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

I now have this working in Win 7 from the task scheduler as I need.  Thank you to @netubsi and @firerat of LinuxQuestionsorg and @konsolebox for the suggestions that lead to a solution.

Here is what I did:

```
cmd /c net use T: '\\server\share'        # Created a separate temporary share for Cygwin
DEST="/cygdrive/T/User/FolderBackup/"     # Use temporary Share in Destination
rsync -avuz --copy-links "$SRC" "$DEST"   # Do backup
cmd /c net use T: /delete                 # Remove temporary share
```

It appears that in WIN 7 the share created in Windows is NOT available to a Cygwin script, IF it is launced from the Win 7 task scheduler.  It IS available if the script is launced from the Cygwin command line.  It also appears that this is NOT an issue in Win Vista.

This seems odd to me.  Perhaps there is another explanation that I am missing.  However I am just relieved to have this working!!

Comment: Old question, but I just ran into this exact issue with win10 64 bit and this fixed it.  Now my rsync runs from Windows Scheduler.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use the network address directly in cygwin:

```
DEST="//server/share/User/FolderBackup"
```

Cygwin mounts local and mapped drives under /cygdrive. Using taskscheduler in win7 if you list the contents of /cygdrive, all you will see are local drives???

Answer (score 0):

First option is to run your script as

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "~/rsync_Windows_Backup >> ~/Documents_cron.log 2>&1"
```

If you want to capture the stderr output as well, you have to place it in front to copy the fd of the file, and not of stdout.

Make sure that `rsync_Windows_Backup` has executable permissions. Running `ls -l ~/rsync_Windows_Backup` should show it.

If it doesn't work, try to use absolute paths. On your Cygwin screen where the current direcory shows `~` in the prompt type `pwd` which would show something like

```
User@System ~
$ pwd
/home/User
```

Basing from that as an example your command should now be like:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/home/User/rsync_Windows_Backup >> /home/User/Documents_cron.log 2>&1"
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion and report back.  I think what I have already may be equivalent, but mine is not working.  My suspicion is that the issue may reside in the differences between WIN 7 and Vista in areas like NTLM, etc.  My syntax are working in Vista.

Comment: I realized that I should add a couple of points of clarification that the rsync error I summarized may not make clear.  The backup is between two nodes on a Microsoft LAN.  The receiver is Vista and the sender is WIN 7.  The receiver is reached with a drive mapping to J:.  The sender BASH script does seem to start on the sender but fails with the rsync errors: rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32); rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/J/DocumentsBackup" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: I tried the suggested changes but got the same result.  Any thougths on the NTLM and permissions, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: @dpminusa I'm sorry. I've been reading your replies and thinking but I'm actually out of ideas. Somehow I think you can ask a thread about it in superuser.com. At least you now know that it's not really a scripting problem.

Comment: By the way I'm not getting much how things are mapped, but are you sure that J: is mounted and that you could access it manually via a cygwin terminal? e.g. `cd /cygdrive/J`

Comment: Yes.  cd /cygdrive/J/  succeeds and a cp -p works.  I am wondering if I need to change the user that the Task Manager is set to use.  The current user has been added to the receiver though with the same password.  The error message I get seems to indicate the Task Scheduler will not let the script read the share though as that user.  The user is an administrator on the sender but not the receiver.  I can change that and see what happens.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @dpminusa I think the problem might lie on cygwin as well. Can you access cygwin and /cygdrive/J as that user you use to run through Task Scheduler? I mean not the one you currently use interactively. Or is the user you use for your desktop, and the one you use on Task Scheduler the same?

Comment: I use RDP and do login as the user that is set in the Task Scheduler.  I was thinking about the idea you are expressing though. There are several users to pick from.  If I understand right it is the credentials of the user A/C on the receiver you use for access that is key.  I will double check that and elevate it to the administrator group if it is not now.

Comment: I use RDP and login as the user that is set in the Task Scheduler.  I was thinking about your idea. There are several users to pick from.  If I understand right it is the credentials of the user A/C on the receiver you use for access that is key.  I will double check that and elevate it to the administrator group if it is not now as a test.

Comment: I also looked at the Local Security Policies differrence between WIN 7 and VISTA, since it does work in VISTA.  There are several differences.  I was going to try to set the WIN 7 additional NTLM related policies to the same as VISTA.  That may not be the totality of the issue though.  THis is very frustrating.  Somebody must have encountered this somewhere.  It would seem to be a level one issue overall.  Thanks for the continuing encouragement.

Comment: I tried a whole new set of ideas.  Nothing helped. Added the user to the Local Policies where indicated by other forums on the receiver and sender, created a Powershell wrapper to test and control the environment, add the -R relative parameter to Rsync. Used a Windows path for the destination, changed the task scheduler start in dir.